# make picture size uniform in size

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a row with cards and images. I can see that the columns are not the same size (see picture). Do I need to set width and height for the images that the three are uniform in size?

I would appreciate your help!

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKEM0.png)

Here is my code:

```
<div class="row justify-content-md-center">

<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
  <div class="os-animation" data-animation="fadeInLeft">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/Bild_18.JPG" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="pricing-column text-center">
      <h3>Lorem</h3>
      <p class="ptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
      <div class="pricing-features text-sm-left">
        <h4><span class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
        </h4>
      </div>
      <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" href="/agostar" id="btn_1">mehr Erfahren</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
  <div class="os-animation" data-animation="fadeInUp">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/Bild_10.JPG" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="pricing-column text-center">

      <h3>Lorem</h3>
      <p class="ptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
      <div class="pricing-features text-sm-left">
        <h4><span class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
        </h4>
      </div>
      <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" href="/agotable" id="btn_1">mehr Erfahren</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 col-lg-4">
  <div class="os-animation" data-animation="fadeInRight">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="/images/Bild_120.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="pricing-column text-center">
      <h3>Lorem</h3>
      <p class="ptext">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor</p>
      <div class="pricing-features text-sm-left">
        <h4><span class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor
        </h4>
      </div>
      <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" href="/custom" id="btn_1">mehr Erfahren</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes just apply height to it. Here is the sample http://jsfiddle.net/fW22a/3/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Hello you have 3 ways to achieve such design:

1. Add class `<div class="card h-100">`, that will give you 100% height.
2. Use Bootstrap equal-height columns [Check this link](http://Check%20this%20link%20http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/)
3. You can achieve it by using a template such as follows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Card</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  

<div class="card-group">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">It's a broader card with text below as a natural lead-in to extra content. This content is a little longer.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">It's a broader card with text below as a natural lead-in to extra content. This content is a little longer.This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      <small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: somehow this doesn't work for me. My images are still different sizes.

Comment: Even though your images have different sizes you can create a css class that have dynamic properties that'll make all images alike

Answer (score 0):

If you want your images to all be the same size, you can set them as the `background-image` property on a div. Since `padding-bottom` is based on the width of the element, you can use it to create a fixed aspect ratio that all of your images will respect, as demonstrated in the `.standardizedImage` divs.

Using `background-size: cover` will crop to fit as seen below, if you want to display the entire image, though possibly at the cost of blank space to the top or sides, use `background-size: contain`

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 100px;
}
p {
  padding: 10px;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}

.standardizedImage {
  padding-bottom: 40%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<h3>As images</h3>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/100" />
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>
<div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/100" />
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</div><div class="card">
  <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/300/120" />
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>

<h3>As background images</h3>
<div class="card">
  <div class="standardizedImage" style="background-image: url(https://www.fillmurray.com/300/100);"></div>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="standardizedImage" style="background-image: url(https://www.fillmurray.com/300/100);"></div>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="standardizedImage" style="background-image: url(https://www.fillmurray.com/300/120);"></div>
  <p>Content goes here.</p>
</div>
```